# Delayed payment after placing order

Tags: magento

After placing order customer gets email with information about this order what includes payment method. If customer doesn't pay the order on the page where did he place it, the order still exists in customers acoount as pending or processing (due to payment method).

Where or what should I look to make link for payment for unpaid orders?

Or should they just "reorder" it?

Comment: Which payment method are you using on it ?

Comment: Currently now - Dotpay. But maybe I switch to PayU

Comment: Maybe I could send info in email. Like "Your order # is still unpaid. Please, proceed the #link# to pay it"